# Modified data when using sqlite3

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, discord.js, node-sqlite3

I'm a discord bot developer and I use an SQLite database for my bot. I installed `sqlite3` by npm command and I worked with it, there was no problem, but now I can't use it because it modifies values. I have a bit of code here:

```js
const ghostChannels = await new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
  client.db.all(`SELECT * FROM "Ghosts"`, (err, rows) =>
    err ? reject(err) : resolve(rows)
  )
);
ghostChannels.forEach(async (channel) => {
  const guildchannel = await message.member.guild.channels.cache.get(
    channel.id
  );
  console.log(channel.id);
  console.log(guildchannel);
  const mess = await guildchannel.send(message.member);
  await mess.delete();
});
```

Unfortunately it returns an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError TypeError: channel.send is not a function
```

[image]

So I looked at the `id`, and saw that it's not the same ID as in the database:

[image]

I don't know how to fix it, so if someone knows, tell me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you try to store snowflakes as integers (e.g. `988185997772738610`), while you should store them as strings (`"988185997772738610"`). As these IDs are greater than 53 bits ([`MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)), JavaScript has difficulty interpreting them. It can only safely represent integers between -(2<sup>53</sup> - 1) and 2<sup>53</sup> - 1.

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Max safe integer | `9007199254740992` |
| Your integer | `988185997772738610` |
| Your integer becomes | `988185997772738600` |

As you can see, every discord ID/snowflake's last two digits become `0` if they're stored as integers. You can even try it below:

```js
console.log(988185997772738610)
// => 988185997772738600
console.log('988185997772738610')
// => "988185997772738610"
```

So to solve your problem, make sure you insert the channel (and other) IDs as strings into the database.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you do it in a wrong way? calling in any `database` need some `gateway` (idk the exact name). for ex:

```
const ghostChannels = await new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
  client.db.all(`SELECT * FROM "Ghosts"`, (err, rows) =>
    err ? reject(err) : resolve(rows)
  )
);
ghostChannels.forEach(async (channel) => {
  const guildchannel = await message.member.guild.channels.cache.get(
    channel.id
  );
  console.log(channel.id);
  console.log(guildchannel);
  const mess = await channel.send(message.member);
  await mess.delete();
});
```

since you called your `guildchannel` to `db`
your:

```
const mess = await channel.send(message.member);
```

should be:

```
const mess = await guildchannel.send(message.member);
```

EDIT:

I've seen that `guildchannel` shows as `undefined`, you can try:

```
await guildchannel.channel?.send
```

or something like this:

```
const chan = message.guild.channels.cache.get(`${channel.id}`)
chan.send("set")
```

Comment: I'm sorry it's just a typo, the error is really that it did not get the good id, it should be 988185997772738610 but it returns 988185997772738600